# KMP table satement difficulty

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, substring, dynamic-programming

Please explain why are we subsituting the value of j by next[j-1] in the following code:
http://computing.dcu.ie/~humphrys/Notes/String/kmp.html
follow the link to know about the table concept

```
i = 0

next[i] = 0
i++
j = 0


while ( i < m )
{
 if ( pattern[j] == pattern[i] )
 {
     next[i] = j+1
     i++
     j++
 }
 else ( pattern[j] != pattern[i] )
 {
     if ( j > 0 )
      j = next[j-1]   //this part i am not able to figure out
                      //why don't we just decrement j-1?

 else ( j == 0 )
 {
  next[i] = 0
  i++
  j = 0             
 }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `j` keeps trace of the length of matching so far and `i` keeps trace of the position of the string currently is being processed. So if a matching of `j` length fails at position `i` the function tries to find the longest of the smaller than `j` length matching. so it changes `j` to `next[j - 1]` keeping the i at the same place.

Note that next[x] contains the length of the longest match so far. if matching at ith index for length j fails, it is sure that there is no prefix of the text of length j that matches here. So we should look up the matching at `j - 1` and it keeps trying until a matching with some positive length is found with the prefix of the string or j becomes 0.

Comment: so why don't we just decrement j by 1 ?

Comment: say this string, `ABACABA`, now when i is 6, the prefix-suffix matching is 3, so j is 3. Now let's append A in the end. So it becomes, `ABACABAA`, Now A doesn't match with C, so let's decrement j by 1 and it goes to 2, pattern[2] = 'A', so patter[2] matches with the last character and we get the matching of length 3, which is not true. But note that according to the original algorithm, next[2] = 1, so we'd get j = next[j - 1] = next[ 3 - 1 ] = 1 implementing that algorithm. Then pattern[j] = pattern[7], so pattern[7] = 1. This is just a case to make the answer clearer